# ALB health is failing showing unhealthy on port 80

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have 2 app servers attached to ALB.
The health check on port 80 is failing and returning unhealthy.

Below is my listener configuration.

[image]

And here is the target group configuration. health check path is /

[image]

Health check setting

[image]

Comment: Can you post TG's heath check settings please?

Comment: @Marcin Have added it

Comment: They seem fine. What HTTP code is your root `/` returning? Sometimes its a redirection response (303, or 302), instead of 200. In this case your HCs would fail as they expect 200.

Comment: @Marcin Health checks failed with these codes: [503]

Comment: Is your application working? Can you access it?

Comment: @Marcin my apache2 server is running. 
Basically it's a backend server which holds are APIs

Comment: Ok. But if you curl it with the `/` path, e.g. `curl http://<ip-address>/` does it work? ALB expects correct answer from the root path, not from, e.g. `/api`.

Comment: @Marcin if I perform a curl operation as well it gives me the same error.

503 Service Unavailable

Comment: Ok. Makes sense now. So you have to change the HC setting's `Path` to whatever is your api responding to. Maybe its `/api` or something similar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220537/discussion-between-sumanth-shetty-and-marcin).

Comment: Hi @Marcin, We got it working we gave the absolute path for the health check "ip/api/****". Also to note we didn't have any web pages on the server.
Thank you so much for the input

Comment: Glad to hear that. If you don't mind I will provide an answer for future reference:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments and chat discussion.

The issue was due to **incorrect `Path`** used in the ALB health check.

The **solution** was to replace the `Path` from `/` to the correct one which has general form of `/api/****`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63683667/filtering-the-detailed-bill-generated-by-aws-account-according-to-az-in-aws