# Filtering the detailed bill generated by AWS account according to Region in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, billing

I am working on a project and all the project resource is on 'me-south-1'
I have other resources things in other regions.

I need to send a detailed bill to the client.
could anyone suggest me,How can I filter it according to the region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For detailed billing (with the ability to filter) the best approach is to use [Cost Explorer](https://aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/aws-cost-explorer/).

By using this service you can apply a range of filters (including region), this can also be done [programmatically](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ce.html).

Be aware that using this service does charge `$0.01` per request.

Comment: Hope you're doing well and safe.
Could you help me out of this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65234984/aws-code-pipeline-is-failing-at-deployment-stage-by-timing-out